# *Still Stumped* Deconflicting two R Packages with same library name (sentiment and sentiment140)

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I run R on a webserver and one of the packages I use is "sentiment", an old package used for sentiment analysis. I'm not even sure its still around and/or widely used. There is a new package, "sentiment140" that I would like to use on my server, but to call it, it also uses the library(sentiment) command. How can I install and use both packages?

Comment: This must be a real head scratcher... no answers :(

Comment: Do you need to be able to use both packages at the same time? If so you'll need to rename one of them.  If not you could get away with some trickery with library locations...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

I assume you have an old package already installed (e.g. the `sentiment` package) and you want to install a new one with the same name. We are going to trick `R` into thinking the name of the package is something else (whatever you want to call it).

1. Download the source for the new package.
2. Untar and unzip if needed.
3. In the base directory for the package's source code, there should be a file called `DESCRIPTION`.
4. Key Step --> Edit the `Package:` line in this file, giving it a new package name (e.g. change `Package: sentiment` to `Package: sentiment2`).
5. From the command line, install the package. `R CMD INSTALL package`.

You should now be able to load the package using whatever name you chose above, e.g. `library(sentiment2)`.